# What permissions do I need if database a contains a stored procedure that inserts into a table in database b (same machine)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a stored procedure in `database a` that contains dynamic sql to perform an insert into a table in `database b`.  What permissions does the executing user need on `database b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how the Stored Procedure was created

In the table `mysql.proc` (physical home of Stored Procedures), there is am ENUM  column called `security_type` defined as `enum('INVOKER','DEFINER')`.

If a Stored Procedure was defined as `DEFINER` and the calling user has the [EXECUTE privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute), then all grants are proxied and the calling user can run everything in the Stored Procedure. Nevertheless, you will be able to run it.

If a Stored Procedure was defined as `INVOKER`, then the calling user needs to have all necessary grants before the calling user can run everything in the Stored Procedure.

If you are in database A running `CALL B.MyProc()` as myuser@'%', then `myuser@'%'` needs to have the [EXECUTE privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) to even call Stored Procedures.

In your case, if you are in database A running `CALL MyProc()` as myuser@'%', then myuser@'%' needs the database-level grants to database B defined. SUGGESTION: Move the Stored Procedure to database B, give the user the [EXECUTE privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) and run running `CALL B.MyProc()`.

Answer (score 1):

if the procedure uses execute as owner then the owner of the proc needs rights to database b and the table in database b.
if the procedure does not use execute as owner then the calling user needs rights to database b and the table in database b.
if cross-database ownership is on, then "it depends"
here is a link that speaks to options there:
[Cross-Database Ownership Chaining](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1782/understanding-cross-database-ownership-chaining-in-sql-server/)